# Are there any cases where "out of" is dead wrong or sounds awkward?

Tags: writing-style

The [question about "*he looked out the window*" vs. "*he looked out **of** the window*"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233258/use-of-expression-out-of/233638#233638) has already been asked and answered satisfactorily: apparently it's a matter of taste and *de gustibus non est disputandum*.

Now English is admirably flexible but it cannot be *infinitely* flexible, hence my question: are there any specific cases where I should better opt for the "*out **of***" or rather for the bare "*out*" lest I sound like the well-meaning illiterate I really am?

---

OK, after two days of silence I gather that there's no easy rule of thumb, thus one can rely only on his own Sprachgefühl. Anyway thanks for trying.

Comment: Could you supply some examples that you think might not be okay? "I got out (of) bed to answer this question" is certainly incorrect without the 'of'.

Comment: "Out Africa" wouldn't win any Oscars.

Comment: "The umpire called the batter out of" would be wrong, I suppose.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Actually, I imagine "Out Africa" would make a pretty good art house film.

Comment: John Lawler lists some restrictions on usage in the is-it-really-a-duplicate?

Comment: I doubt you all are going to run out of examples any time soon.

Comment: All right, if you're looking for strict rules you'll better rule out English, I know - that's one of the reasons why I love it. But would anyone try to squeeze at least a vague, rickety, faint guideline? _Pleeease!_ :-)

Comment: Nice question.  The opposite of out is "in," and there is a definite difference between "He walked into the room" vs. "He walked in the room."  (The former means he entered the room, while the latter means he was already in the room, perhaps pacing.)  There doesn't seem to be an analogous pattern for out. I wonder if physical movement has something to do with the question?  "She walked out of the room," "He moved out of his apartment," "They walked out of the meeting," etc. would all sound odd without the "of."

Comment: @Randall Stewart: Well, if you want to stretch it a bit there would be a "_he walked (long) outside the house_ (perhaps pacing)" vs. "_he walked out of the house_ (slamming the door)". The more we dig, the more we find... will there ever be an end to it?

Comment: Hmmm, **physical movement**... are you meaning "_he looked out the window_" but "_he climbed out of **the** window_"? This sounds definitely  promising! Wouldn't you make into a _maybe-so_ answer?

Comment: @Chiron: I appreciate the encouragement, but I'm reluctant to submit an answer for such a thin hypothesis.  I'm hoping others may find counterexamples.  There are the phrases "out of order" or "We're all out of tickets" in which "out" is paired with "of" without any kind of physical movement.   (Although "out" in those two examples seems idiomatic and doesn't have much to do with positioning relative to a container.) But in the end, I only have half-baked ideas and not an answer.

Comment: @Randall Stewart: "_A brilliant intuition is the seed of any great theory_". Someone said it but I'll be damned if I remember who :-)

Comment: *In one ear and out the other* sounds wrong to me when you add an *of*. But Google shows that the version with *of* is definitely in use. I think this shows that some people always add *of* after the preposition *out*.

Comment: [Ngram for previous comment](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+ear+and+out+the%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+one+ear+and+out+of%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+one+ear+and+out+the%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cone+ear+and+out+of%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=7&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20ear%20and%20out%20the%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20ear%20and%20out%20of%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20ear%20and%20out%20the%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20ear%20and%20out%20of%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hypothesis.  I haven't found any authoritative source, but neither have I found any counter-examples.

I think there are 3 descriptive rules at play:

1. If the sentence uses "out" in reference to the *enclosure* that is being exited, "of" is always used:

   - Move out of my apartment. (Not "Move out my apartment.")
   - Get out of the armed forces.  (Not "Get out the armed forces.")
   - Walk out of a relationship.  (Not "Walk out a relationship.")
   - Get out of Dodge. (Not "Get out Dodge.")
   - Get out of the car. (Not, "Get out the car.")
   - Air leaked out of the balloon. (I have heard expressions similar to "Air leaked out the balloon" or "Water leaked out the tub." But they have an unsophisticated feel.)
2. If the sentence uses "out" in reference to the *portal* used to exit the enclosure, then "of" is often omitted:

   - Walk out the door.
   - Look out the window.
   - Air leaked out the hole.
   - Water gushed out the drain
3. Even when referring to a portal, "of" can mean "through." So you can optionally include "of" if you want to emphasize the portal in some way:

   - Walk out of the door.
   - Look out of the window.
   - Air leaked out of the hole.
   - Water gushed out of the drain.

Comment: There really should be an authoritative source for this, but I can't find one. Note that *out of* is [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+the+window%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cout+of+the+window%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cout+the+window%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cout+of+the+window%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20the%20window%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20the%20window%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20the%20window%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20the%20window%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) in the U.S. than the U.K.

Comment: So if many people in the U.K. always use *out of* and never *out*, you're not going to find any expressions where *out of* sounds really wrong.